# Why does this variadic tuple type with a union not appear to allow a matching type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript4.0, variadic-tuple-types

This code appears to compile in TS 4.3, but not before that (i.e. 4.0.5, etc). It's confusing to me why adding a union to `undefined` causes the 2nd assignment to not compile. I'm trying to understand what changed that allows this to work in 4.3, but I'm unsure of what to search for (like a bug fix, etc). Also, I'm looking for a proper workaround before TS 4.3 to be used until the version can be upgraded. For instance, should I just add `| undefined` on the the type definition of `y`, or is there another way to get the types to fit for the 2nd assignment?

```
export type StringKeyOf<T> = Extract<keyof T, string>;

export interface GenericEvent<TEventName, TData> {
  eventName: TEventName;
  data: TData;
}

export type EventTypeByEventName = {
  [eventName: string]: any;
};

export type GenericEventsFromMap<TEventMap extends EventTypeByEventName, K2 extends keyof TEventMap> = {
  [K in K2]: GenericEvent<K, TEventMap[K]>;
}[K2];

export class EventService<TEventMap extends EventTypeByEventName> {
  public setup<T extends Array<StringKeyOf<TEventMap>>>(managerId: string, eventNames: [...T]) {
    const y: GenericEvent<T[number], TEventMap[T[number]]> = null as any;

    // this assignment works
    const z: GenericEventsFromMap<TEventMap, T[number]> = y;

    // this assignment gives:
    // Type 'GenericEvent<T[number], TEventMap[T[number]]>' is not assignable to type 'GenericEventsFromMap<TEventMap, T[number]>'.
    const z2: GenericEventsFromMap<TEventMap, T[number]> | undefined = y;
  }
}
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=2&module=6&ts=4.0.5#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDKMoEsB2BzAaWEQHkAzAHgBUA+OAXjgFERMBDAYxgoGtiIycKgBo4AZ0y48NANwAoOaEiw4uGMChlOqAOLAcGrByYA3fdyqnzAOTYBbYKKoARNjDZ0A3nLhxgZnBhbBwAuIStA4OB5XwATNzYwlwT5AF8FJWh4JBRmAJgqZGAAIUQIoPtURm9fAG1-G0qwiWx8AF0wthxENPlFcCyEIrg9A2xjfLEAMSgIOwBZNjBqcsWwP1Z9WLE880KUUvKo0QIAJg31HG24PkQBcPy1umqfOFqCVRw4M46R-UMJuYKAQnKslu82rI5Kl3qc2n1MioOAAbNhiHblNAaExGYArR5LC5bDH5fYlMr5KJeV5gACuACNkUZxMAYLTllQiVcdgBBKBQNiICgYVqEYjkfHmJ40GgACjsXTYeA0AElYs1JPhRA1IpUxGFagA6Y1UNoASjgNV8cA4EBwEjgiDCowB5WotRwtLs9I0bVBBLAtSoHq9PqgbUhDDgnuRyLgaPj3Ri1tevgA9GmEAALLA7NFiLB4HAOQJwADu0B4YlTNrtDoAXs7-uNytNZgslpLAmsnCHvb7no6+ta4Bns7n4+jC8XzHA8FgzPqa2OyXAAOQulv5d2e-vh-1S8HB3dhiM0NeqHY4CDwfPTtiM1AwCBDXIb5tGVszOZrLswHtCH2p7noaNa2va8D1qcTZjJ+kzfh2HJgmAvYngOcAAD5wLSVzAGQuDALEUY9K86SpEAA)

Comment: Looks like bug was https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43152 which was fixed by https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/43202.  As for a "proper" workaround, I'm not sure how to gauge that.  You can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJ4A6N), but is that "proper"?  Let me know if you want any of this as an answer.

Comment: @jcalz thanks. I hadn't tried that exact workaround, but it makes sense. You can add it as an answer if u want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug in question was [microsoft/TypeScript#43152](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43152), and was fixed in [microsoft/TypeScript#43202](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/43202), which was merged into the main  branch on 2021-03-19 and eventually released with TypeScript 4.3.

How did I find this?  If you go to https://typescript.azureedge.net/indexes/pre-releases.json you will see a list of TypeScript pre-release versions that you can use in [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org) with the `ts=` query parameter.  Via [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), you can fairly quickly locate the last version where the bug is present and the first version where the bug is absent.

In your case, the bug was [present in `4.3.0-dev.20210316`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=2&module=6&ts=4.3.0-dev.20210316#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDKMoEsB2BzAaWEQHkAzAHgBUA+OAXjgFERMBDAYxgoGtiIycKgBo4AZ0y48NANwAoOaEiw4uGMChlOqAOLAcGrByYA3fdyqnzAOTYBbYKKoARNjDZ0A3nLhxgZnBhbBwAuIStA4OB5XwATNzYwlwT5AF8FJWh4JBRmAJgqZGAAIUQIoPtURm9fAG1-G0qwiWx8AF0wthxENPlFcCyEIrg9A2xjfLEAMSgIOwBZNjBqcsWwP1Z9WLE880KUUvKo0QIAJg31HG24PkQBcPy1umqfOFqCVRw4M46R-UMJuYKAQnKslu82rI5Kl3qc2n1MioOAAbNhiHblNAaExGYArR5LC5bDH5fYlMr5KJeV5gACuACNkUZxMAYLTllQiVcdgBBKBQNiICgYVqEYjkfHmJ40GgACjsXTYeA0AElYs1JPhRA1IpUxGFagA6Y1UNoASjgNV8cA4EBwEjgiDCowB5WotRwtLs9I0bVBBLAtSoHq9PqgbUhDDgnuRyLgaPj3Ri1tevgA9GmEAALLA7NFiLB4HAOQJwADu0B4YlTNrtDoAXs7-uNytNZgslpLAmsnCHvb7no6+ta4Bns7n4+jC8XzHA8FgzPqa2OyXAAOQulv5d2e-vh-1S8HB3dhiM0NeqHY4CDwfPTtiM1AwCBDXIb5tGVszOZrLswHtCH2p7noaNa2va8D1qcTZjJ+kzfh2HJgmAvYngOcAAD5wLSVzAGQuDALEUY9K86SpEAA) but [absent in `4.3.0-dev.20210323`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=2&module=6&ts=4.3.0-dev.20210323#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDKMoEsB2BzAaWEQHkAzAHgBUA+OAXjgFERMBDAYxgoGtiIycKgBo4AZ0y48NANwAoOaEiw4uGMChlOqAOLAcGrByYA3fdyqnzAOTYBbYKKoARNjDZ0A3nLhxgZnBhbBwAuIStA4OB5XwATNzYwlwT5AF8FJWh4JBRmAJgqZGAAIUQIoPtURm9fAG1-G0qwiWx8AF0wthxENPlFcCyEIrg9A2xjfLEAMSgIOwBZNjBqcsWwP1Z9WLE880KUUvKo0QIAJg31HG24PkQBcPy1umqfOFqCVRw4M46R-UMJuYKAQnKslu82rI5Kl3qc2n1MioOAAbNhiHblNAaExGYArR5LC5bDH5fYlMr5KJeV5gACuACNkUZxMAYLTllQiVcdgBBKBQNiICgYVqEYjkfHmJ40GgACjsXTYeA0AElYs1JPhRA1IpUxGFagA6Y1UNoASjgNV8cA4EBwEjgiDCowB5WotRwtLs9I0bVBBLAtSoHq9PqgbUhDDgnuRyLgaPj3Ri1tevgA9GmEAALLA7NFiLB4HAOQJwADu0B4YlTNrtDoAXs7-uNytNZgslpLAmsnCHvb7no6+ta4Bns7n4+jC8XzHA8FgzPqa2OyXAAOQulv5d2e-vh-1S8HB3dhiM0NeqHY4CDwfPTtiM1AwCBDXIb5tGVszOZrLswHtCH2p7noaNa2va8D1qcTZjJ+kzfh2HJgmAvYngOcAAD5wLSVzAGQuDALEUY9K86SpEAA).  That means we'd need to [search for pull requests merged between 2021-03-16 and 2021-03-23](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/search?p=1&q=merged%3A2021-03-16..2021-03-23&type=issues) and find which one is appropriate.  If we [add the "union" and "undefined" terms to our search](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/search?q=undefined+union+merged%3A2021-03-16..2021-03-23&type=issues) it narrows things down even further.

---

As for a workaround for those unlucky enough to be stuck on a version with this bug, it's not clear what a good one is.  Many obvious fixes fail run into the same bug, since there's no good reason why `X` should not be assignable to `X | undefined`.  The following type assertion seems to work:

```
const z: GenericEventsFromMap<TEventMap, T[number]> | undefined = 
  y as typeof y | undefined; // okay
```

But whether or not it's advisable is hard to say.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=2&module=6&ts=4.0.5#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDKMoEsB2BzAaWEQHkAzAHgBUA+OAXjgFERMBDAYxgoGtiIycKgBo4AZ0y48NANwAoOaEiw4uGMChlOqAOLAcGrByYA3fdyqnzAOTYBbYKKoARNjDZ0A3nLhxgZnBhbBwAuIStA4OB5XwATNzYwlwT5AF8FJWh4JBRmAJgqZGAAIUQIoPtURm9fAG1-G0qwiWx8AF0wthxENPlFcCyEIrg9A2xjfLEAMSgIOwBZNjBqcsWwP1Z9WLE880KUUvKo0QIAJg31HG24PkQBcPy1umqfOFqCVRw4M46R-UMJuYKAQnKslu82rI5Kl3qc2n1MioOAAbNhiHblNAaExGYArR5LC5bDH5fYlMr5KJeV5gACuACNkUZxMAYLTllQiVcdgBBKBQNiICgYVqEYjkfHmJ40GgACjsXTYeA0AElYs1JPhRA1IpUxGFagA6Y1UNoASjgNV8cA4EBwEjgiDCowB5WotRwtLs9I0bVBBLAtSoHq9PqgbUhDDgnuRyLgaPj3Ri1tt9vgAC9nf9xuVprMFktJYE1k4Q97fXQAD5wWlXYBkXDAWJRxDxnY5YD3VvV2uxeuN2IyOAAemHcAgPEFr3SqSAA)